# looping through days of the week checking against a multidimensional array - PHP

Tags: php

I'm looping through the days of the week and checking an array for each day. I can output existing/matching values but when there is no corresponding value I can't output a single zero I output the 3 zeroes if there are 3 items in the array. How can I output a single zero? Here is my code:

```
$day1='9-9-2019';
$day2='9-10-2019';
$day3='9-11-2019';
$day4='9-12-2019';
$day5='9-13-2019';
$day6='9-14-2019';
$day7='9-15-2019';


$records = array(
    array(
        "date_sub" => "9-11-2019",
        "timeSum" => "99:00:00"
    ),
    array(
        "date_sub" => "9-12-2019",
        "timeSum" => "01:40:00"
    ),
    array(
        "date_sub" => "9-13-2019",
        "timeSum" => "00:20:00"
    )
);


for ($i = 1 ; $i < 8; $i++) {

    if ($i==1) { // is there anything for monday?

        foreach ($records as $row) {

            $date_sub=$row["date_sub"];
            $timeSum=$row["timeSum"];

            if ($date_sub==$day1) {echo "$date_sub: $timeSum";} else {echo "$day1: 0:00";}
        }
    }

    if ($i==2) { // is there anything for tuesday?

        foreach ($records as $row) {

            $date_sub=$row["date_sub"];
            $timeSum=$row["timeSum"];

            if ($date_sub==$day2) {echo "$date_sub: $timeSum";} else {echo "$day2: 0:00";}
        }
    }

    if ($i==3) { // is there anything for wednesday?

        foreach ($records as $row) { 

            $date_sub=$row["date_sub"];
            $timeSum=$row["timeSum"];

            if ($date_sub==$day3) {echo "$date_sub: $timeSum";} else {echo "$day3: 0:00";}
        }
    }

    if ($i==4) { // is there anything for thursday?

        foreach ($records as $row) { 

            $date_sub=$row["date_sub"];
            $timeSum=$row["timeSum"];

            if ($date_sub==$day4) {echo "$date_sub: $timeSum";} else {echo "$day4: 0:00";}
        }
    }

    if ($i==5) { // is there anything for friday?

        foreach ($records as $row) { 

            $date_sub=$row["date_sub"];
            $timeSum=$row["timeSum"];

            if ($date_sub==$day5) {echo "$date_sub: $timeSum";} else {echo "$day5: 0:00";}
        }
    }

    if ($i==6) { // is there anything for saturday?

        foreach ($records as $row) { 

            $date_sub=$row["date_sub"];
            $timeSum=$row["timeSum"];

            if ($date_sub==$day6) {echo "$date_sub: $timeSum";} else {echo "$day6: 0:00";}
        }
    }

    if ($i==7) { // is there anything for sunday?

        foreach ($records as $row) {

            $date_sub=$row["date_sub"];
            $timeSum=$row["timeSum"];

            if ($date_sub==$day7) {echo "$date_sub: $timeSum";} else {echo "$day7: 0:00";}
        }
    }
echo "<br />\n";
}
```

Am I on the right track or do I need to restructure my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of repetition in your code and there is a simpler method which starts with creating an array of the dates in your week and a value of 0 in them.  I've done this with `array_fill_keys()` and used the individual days, you could add them directly in if you can.

The loop over the records and put the value in the corresponding element of the `$week` array...

```
$week = array_fill_keys([$day1, $day2,$day3,$day4,$day5,$day6,$day7]
    , 0);

foreach ( $records as $record ) {
    $week[$record["date_sub"]] = $record["timeSum"];
}

print_r($week);
```

which will give...

```
Array
(
    [9-9-2019] => 0
    [9-10-2019] => 0
    [9-11-2019] => 99:00:00
    [9-12-2019] => 01:40:00
    [9-13-2019] => 00:20:00
    [9-14-2019] => 0
    [9-15-2019] => 0
)
```

You can then loop over this and display it how you need...

```
foreach ( $week as $date => $value )    {
    echo $date."-".$value.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my setup didn't accept your array_fill_keys line so I just set up a separate  array for the days of the week before it and referenced that array in the array_fill_keys function.

Answer (score 0):

There are surely many other ways to handle your problem. For example.

Find monday for given date week.

```
$monday = strtotime('this week monday', strtotime('2019-09-10'));
```

or replace it with
`$monday = strtotime('this week monday');`
if you're interested in current week.

```
$day = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp($monday);

$records = [
    [
        "date_sub" => "9-11-2019",
        "timeSum" => "99:00:00"
    ],
    [
        "date_sub" => "9-12-2019",
        "timeSum" => "01:40:00"
    ],
    [
        "date_sub" => "9-13-2019",
        "timeSum" => "00:20:00"
    ]
];

for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $entryFound = false;

    foreach($records as $record) {
        if($day == DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d-Y', $record['date_sub'])){
            $entryFound = true;
            echo $day->format('m-d-Y'), " : ", $record['timeSum'];
        }
    }

    if(!$entryFound) {
        echo $day->format('m-d-Y'), " : 0:00";
    }

    $day->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

I loop through `$records` array every time and compare because I assume there could be multiple entries for every day and also entries for other dates outside of the week you're interested in.

---

You could also transform `$records` to something like this

```
Array(
    "9-11-2019" => "99:00:00",
    ...
)
```

to make the `foreach` loop even simpler

```
foreach($records as $date_sub => $timeSum) {
    if($day == DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d-Y', $date_sub)){
        $entryFound = true;
        echo $day->format('m-d-Y'), " : ", $timeSum;
    }
}
```

---

You could also omit comparing it as DateTime objects and just go with strings like so:

```
foreach ...
    if($day->format('m-d-Y') === $date_sub){
...
```